# What is wrong with this C# XML Deserialization code?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I've read as many article as I can find, I've done serialization this way before but the life of me I cannot figure out why the following isn't working correctly.

Assistance appreciated.

Given this code:

POCO classes for deseralized response:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class MyResponseClass
{
    [XmlElement("response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot]
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement("error")]
    public Error Error { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("sid")]
    public string Sid { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot]
public class Error
{
    [XmlElement("error_msg")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Request and response handling code:

```
var webClient = _webClientWrapperFactory.Create();
var url = "https://serviceendpoint.com";
var responseString = webClient.DownloadString(url);

MyResponseClass result;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyResponseClass));
using (var reader = new StringReader(responseString))
{
result = (MyResponseClass) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
return result;
```

Returns this response:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><response><error><error_msg>CANNOT_LOGIN</error_msg></error></response>
```

Deserialization attempt throws this error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is an error in XML document (1, 57).

EDIT:
Inner Exception:

```
{"<response xmlns=''> was not expected."}
```

Comment: InnerException: `"<response xmlns=''> was not expected."`

Comment: try to remove `XmlRoot` attribute from `Response` and `Error` since it's only allowed at the root object of the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a quick instance of `MyResponseClass` and serialized it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyResponseClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <response>
    <error>
      <error_msg>error message text</error_msg>
    </error>
    <sid>(sid string)</sid>
  </response>
</MyResponseClass>
```

So that's what your XML should look like for `MyResponseClass`. Here's the serialization code I used:

```
MyResponseClass result1 = new MyResponseClass
{
    Response = new Response
    {
        Sid = "(sid string)",
        Error = new Error
        {
            ErrorMessage = "error message text"
        }
    }
};

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyResponseClass));
string serialized = "";

using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, result1);
    serialized = textWriter.ToString();
}
```

But that's probably not what you want.

If you want to stick with the XML you have in your question, you need to dispense with `MyResponseClass` and specify that `Response`, as an XML root, is all lowercase:

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement("error")]
    public Error Error { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("sid")]
    public string Sid { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var responseString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><response><error><error_msg>CANNOT_LOGIN</error_msg></error></response>";

var serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));

//using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
//{
//    serializer2.Serialize(textWriter, result1.Response);
//    responseString = textWriter.ToString();
//}

Response result;
using (var reader = new StringReader(responseString))
{
    result = (Response)serializer2.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Ugh, it's always something silly, isn't it?  Thank you.  Your assumption that the XML was immutable was correct - it's a response from a 3rd party service.  Thanks again for the quick assist!